# Adapt a 9-node element routine to a 8-node

Tags: finite-element-method

The function `GenerateGridMesh[a_, b_, nx_, ny_]` creates a grid of 9-node finite elements mesh. I need some help to adapt this routine to create 8 node element mesh. This function has as input data the `a` and `b` which are the grid dimensions, and `nx` and `ny` representing the number of divisions of the mesh in the x and y directions. As an output this function return `allcoords` representing the mesh nodes organized by elements, `meshnodes` that are all the nodes in the mesh ordered in sequence and, the `meshtopology`, that contains the ids of the nodes that composes the elements. The `meshtopology` order is very important and is needed in finite element global vector and matrix assemblage. As a simple example consider the single 9node element illustrated bellow. The `meshtopology` for this example must be ordered as follows: {{1,3,9,7,2,6,8,4,5}}. This is a 9-node element.

[image]

I need the same for a 8-node element like the following:

[image]

`meshtopology` I need: {{1,3,14,12,2,9,13,8}}

The function `GenerateGraphics[nodes_, topology_, order_]` is only for plot purpose.

```
(*a and b are the mesh dimensions*)
(*xn and ny are the number of divisions in the x and y directions*)

GenerateGridMesh[a_, b_, nx_, ny_] := 
  Block[{x = 0., y = 0., dx, dy, meshnodes = {}, i, j, 
    meshtopology = {}, allcoords, k, topolsz, l, order = 2},
   k = 0;
   meshnodes = 
    Flatten[Table[
      Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, a, a/(nx order - order)}], {y, 0, b, 
       b/(ny order - order)}], 1];
   For[i = 1, i < ny, i++,
    l = 1;
    For[j = 1, j < nx, j++,
     AppendTo[
      meshtopology, {l + k, l + 2 + k, 4 nx + l + k, 4 nx - 2 + l + k,
        l + 1 + k, l + 1 + nx 2 + k, l + nx 4 - 1 + k, 
       2 nx + l - 1 + k, 2 nx + l + k}];
     l += 2;
     ];
    k += 4 nx - 2;
    ];
   allcoords = 
    Table[meshnodes[[meshtopology[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[meshtopology]}, {j, 1, Length[meshtopology[[1]]]}];
   {allcoords, meshnodes, meshtopology}
   ];
(*This function generates a mesh graphic*)
GenerateGraphics[nodes_, topology_, order_] := 
  Block[{meshvis, nodevis, v},
   v = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8};
   meshvis = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
      GraphicsComplex[nodes, Polygon[topology[[All, v]]]]}];
   nodevis = 
    Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1, 1}] &, nodes], {Blue, 
       Point[nodes]}}];
   {meshvis, nodevis}
   ];
{allcoords, meshnodes, meshtopology} = GenerateGridMesh[36, 36, 4, 4];
{meshvis, nodevis} = GenerateGraphics[meshnodes, meshtopology, 2];
Show[meshvis, nodevis]
```

This what the code return:

[image]

the `meshtopology` i get:

{{1, 3, 17, 15, 2, 10, 16, 8, 9}, {3, 5, 19, 17, 4, 12, 18, 10, 
  11}, {5, 7, 21, 19, 6, 14, 20, 12, 13}, {15, 17, 31, 29, 16, 24, 30,
   22, 23}, {17, 19, 33, 31, 18, 26, 32, 24, 25}, {19, 21, 35, 33, 20,
   28, 34, 26, 27}, {29, 31, 45, 43, 30, 38, 44, 36, 37}, {31, 33, 47,
   45, 32, 40, 46, 38, 39}, {33, 35, 49, 47, 34, 42, 48, 40, 41}}

This is what i need:

[image]

the `meshtopology` i want:

{{1, 3, 14, 12, 2, 9, 13, 8}, {3, 5, 16, 14, 4, 10, 15, 9}, {5, 7, 18,
   16, 6, 11, 17, 10}, {12, 14, 25, 23, 13, 20, 24, 19}, {14, 16, 27, 
  25, 15, 21, 26, 20}, {16, 18, 29, 27, 17, 22, 28, 21}, {23, 25, 36, 
  34, 24, 31, 35, 30}, {25, 27, 38, 36, 26, 32, 37, 31}, {27, 29, 40, 
  38, 28, 33, 39, 32}}

Comment: Please explain the meaning of inputs in your code, and specify the desired outcome *precisely*. Add what you have tried so far, and how it has not worked. As it is, your question is a job posting, not a request for help.

Comment: @MarcoB I have modified the question trying to explain it better.

Comment: Thank you for adding further details. Still, however: in your bottom specification, and referring to the original numbering scheme, why did you skip original node 16, but not nodes 18 and 20? Should node 16 not have been included?

Comment: @MarcoB I have corrected the figure. Thank you for pointing the mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works as a start:

```
ClearAll[generator, meshPlot]

generator[n_Integer] := Module[
  {allpts, noBodycentered, sortedAndLabeled},
  allpts = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
  noBodycentered = DeleteCases[allpts, {i_, j_} /; OddQ[i j]];
  sortedAndLabeled = MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, SortBy[Last]@noBodycentered]
]

meshPlot[list_List] := ListPlot[Labeled[#1, #2]& @@@list, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

You can use them as follows:

```
generator[7]

(* Out: 
{{0, 0} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 2, {2, 0} -> 3, {3, 0} -> 4, {4, 0} -> 5, {5, 0} -> 6, 
 {6, 0} -> 7, {0, 1} -> 8, {2, 1} -> 9, {4, 1} -> 10, {6, 1} -> 11, {0, 2} -> 12, 
 {1, 2} -> 13, {2, 2} -> 14, {3, 2} -> 15, {4, 2} -> 16, {5, 2} -> 17, {6, 2} -> 18, 
 {0, 3} -> 19, {2, 3} -> 20, {4, 3} -> 21, {6, 3} -> 22, {0, 4} -> 23, {1, 4} -> 24,
 {2, 4} -> 25, {3, 4} -> 26, {4, 4} -> 27, {5, 4} -> 28, {6, 4} -> 29, {0, 5} -> 30, 
 {2, 5} -> 31, {4, 5} -> 32, {6, 5} -> 33, {0, 6} -> 34, {1, 6} -> 35, {2, 6} -> 36,
 {3, 6} -> 37, {4, 6} -> 38, {5, 6} -> 39, {6, 6} -> 40}
*)

meshPlot[generator[7]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! This will help.

Comment: @Diogo You're welcome.

Comment: I like how you detect the vertices for deletion.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ToElementMesh` for that:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1]
Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[
  MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1, -1}] &, mesh["Coordinates"]]]
 ]
```

[image]

The element incidents can then easily be extracted with:

```
ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]]
{{{1, 6, 7, 2, 26, 27, 28, 29}, {2, 7, 8, 3, 28, 30, 31, 32}, {3, 8, 
   9, 4, 31, 33, 34, 35}, {4, 9, 10, 5, 34, 36, 37, 38}, {6, 11, 12, 
   7, 39, 40, 41, 27}, {7, 12, 13, 8, 41, 42, 43, 30}, {8, 13, 14, 9, 
   43, 44, 45, 33}, {9, 14, 15, 10, 45, 46, 47, 36}, {11, 16, 17, 12, 
   48, 49, 50, 40}, {12, 17, 18, 13, 50, 51, 52, 42}, {13, 18, 19, 14,
    52, 53, 54, 44}, {14, 19, 20, 15, 54, 55, 56, 46}, {16, 21, 22, 
   17, 57, 58, 59, 49}, {17, 22, 23, 18, 59, 60, 61, 51}, {18, 23, 24,
    19, 61, 62, 63, 53}, {19, 24, 25, 20, 63, 64, 65, 55}}}
```

Besides that you have many efficient `ElementMesh` utilities documented [in the Scope section here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html).

Comment: Ah, `"QuadElements"` is the default for rectangular domains and serendipity elements are used for quad meshes. I'd have expected bilinear elements for some reason. Both is very good to know!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Yes, exactly right!

Answer (score 2):

#### `GridGraph` + `VertexDelete` + `VertexReplace`:

```
f[n_?OddQ, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{g2, 
  g1 = GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 5, o, ImageSize -> 400]},
  g1 = SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> (Reverse /@ GraphEmbedding[g1])];
  g2 = VertexDelete[g1, Select[Range[n  n], 
    OddQ[#] && EvenQ[Mod[#, n]] && Positive[Mod[#, n]] &]];
  g2 = SetProperty[VertexReplace[g2, Thread[VertexList[g2] -> Range[VertexCount[g2]]]], 
   {VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g2], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   ImagePadding -> 5, o, ImageSize -> 400}];
  {g1, g2}]
```

**Examples:**

```
Row @ f @ 7
```

[image]

```
Row @ f @ 5
```

[image]

```
Row @ f @ 9
```

[image]

Comment: nice graphs! But what is more important to me is the element topology. In my example the elements topology are:{{1, 3, 17, 15, 2, 10, 16, 8, 9}, {3, 5, 19, 17, 4, 12, 18, 10, 
  11}, {5, 7, 21, 19, 6, 14, 20, 12, 13}, {15, 17, 31, 29, 16, 24, 30,
   22, 23}, {17, 19, 33, 31, 18, 26, 32, 24, 25}, {19, 21, 35, 33, 20,
   28, 34, 26, 27}, {29, 31, 45, 43, 30, 38, 44, 36, 37}, {31, 33, 47,
   45, 32, 40, 46, 38, 39}, {33, 35, 49, 47, 34, 42, 48, 40, 41}}

Comment: The topology i need for my example witout the middle nodes is:{{1, 3, 14, 12, 2, 9, 13, 8}, {3, 5, 16, 14, 4, 10, 15, 9}, {5, 7, 18,
   16, 6, 11, 17, 10}, {12, 14, 25, 23, 13, 20, 24, 19}, {14, 16, 27, 
  25, 15, 21, 26, 20}, {16, 18, 29, 27, 17, 22, 28, 21}, {23, 25, 36, 
  34, 24, 31, 35, 30}, {25, 27, 38, 36, 26, 32, 37, 31}, {27, 29, 40, 
  38, 28, 33, 39, 32}}

Comment: @Diogo, is the order of nodes  important? If not `SortBy[VertexList/@FindCycle[f[7][[2]] ,{8}, All]  , Min]` give the same list (except the ordering of nodes in each sublist).

Comment: .. that is, it gives `{{1, 2, 3, 9, 14, 13, 12, 8}, {3, 4, 5, 10, 16, 15, 14, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 
  11, 18, 17, 16, 10}, {23, 24, 25, 20, 14, 13, 12, 19}, {25, 20, 14, 
  15, 16, 21, 27, 26}, {27, 21, 16, 17, 18, 22, 29, 28}, {23, 24, 25, 
  31, 36, 35, 34, 30}, {25, 31, 36, 37, 38, 32, 27, 26}, {27, 32, 38, 
  39, 40, 33, 29, 28}}`

Comment: the `meshtopology` order is very important. But this function(`Find Cycle`) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a quad mesh. Here are some routines I frequently use to generate grids for reactangles, cylinders, and tori:

```
getGridPoints = Compile[
   {{x0, _Real},
    {x1, _Real},
    {y0, _Real},
    {y1, _Real},
    {m, _Integer},
    {n, _Integer},
    {xclosed, True | False},
    {yclosed, True | False}
    },
   Block[{mm, nn, x, y, δx, δy, oo},
    mm = m - Boole[xclosed];
    nn = n - Boole[yclosed];
    δx = (x1 - x0)/(m - 1);
    δy = (y1 - y0)/(n - 1);
    x = x0 - δx;
    y = y0 - δy;
    Flatten[
     Table[
      y += δy;
      x = x0 - δx;
      Table[
       x += δx;
       {x, y},
       {i, 1, mm}],
      {j, 1, nn}],
     1]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

getGridQuads = 
  Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {xclosed, 
     True | False}, {yclosed, True | False}},
   Block[{a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, quads, qq, mm, nn},
    b1 = Boole[xclosed];
    b2 = Boole[yclosed];
    mm = m - b1;
    nn = n - b2;

    quads = Flatten[Table[
       qq = Table[
         a1 = mm (j - 1) + i;
         a2 = mm (j - 1) + i + 1;
         a3 = mm j + i;
         a4 = mm j + i + 1;
         {a1, a2, a4, a3},
         {i, 1, mm - 1}];

       If[xclosed,
        Join[qq,
         a1 = mm (j - 1) + mm;
         a2 = mm (j - 1) + 1;
         a3 = mm (j) + 1;
         a4 = mm (j) + mm;
         {{a1, a2, a4, a3}}
         ],
        qq
        ]
       ,
       {j, 1, nn - 1}], 1];

    If[yclosed,
     qq = Table[
       a1 = mm (nn - 1) + i;
       a2 = mm (nn - 1) + i + 1;
       a3 = i;
       a4 = i + 1;
       {a1, a2, a4, a3},
       {i, 1, mm - 1}];
     If[xclosed,
      a1 = mm nn;
      a2 = mm (nn - 1) 1;
      a3 = nn;
      a4 = 1;
      qq = Join[qq, {{a1, a2, a4, a3}}]
      ];
     Join[quads, qq],
     quads
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

getEdgesFromQuads = Compile[{{q, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{q1, q2, q3, q4},
    q1 = Compile`GetElement[q, 1];
    q2 = Compile`GetElement[q, 2];
    q3 = Compile`GetElement[q, 3];
    q4 = Compile`GetElement[q, 4];
    {
     {Min[q1, q2], Max[q1, q2]},
     {Min[q2, q3], Max[q2, q3]},
     {Min[q3, q4], Max[q3, q4]},
     {Min[q4, q1], Max[q4, q1]}
     }
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Here is our first quad mesh.

```
m = 8;
n = 4;
R = MeshRegion[
  getGridPoints[0, 2, 0, 1, m + 1, n + 1, False, False],
  Polygon[getGridQuads[m + 1, n + 1, False, False]]
  ]
```

[image]

The following should convert an arbitrary quad mesh into your desired format. Feel free to package that into a function.

```
pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
vertexcount = Length[pts];
quads = MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
data = Flatten[getEdgesFromQuads[quads], 1];
edges = DeleteDuplicates[data];
edgemidpts = 0.5 Total[Partition[pts[[Flatten[edges]]], 2], {2}];

allpts = Join[pts, edgemidpts];
ordering = Ordering[Transpose[Transpose[allpts][[{2, 1}]]]];

perm = ConstantArray[0, Length[allpts]];
perm[[ordering]] = Range[Length[allpts]];
edgemidptindices = perm[[vertexcount + 1 ;;]];

edgelookup = SparseArray[
   Rule[
    Join[edges, Transpose[Transpose[edges][[{2, 1}]]]],
    Join[edgemidptindices, edgemidptindices]
    ],
   {vertexcount, vertexcount}
   ];
newtopology = Join[
   Partition[perm[[Flatten[quads]]], 4],
   Partition[Extract[edgelookup, data], 4],
   2
   ];
newpts = allpts[[ordering]];
```

Now, `newpts` contains the positions of all quad corners and all edge midpoints. `newtopology` contains the index lists. The first four entries point to the corners of the quad (in same order as in the original mesh). Index 5 to 8 point to the edge midpoints in order consistent with the first four indices.

A test graphic:

```
Graphics[{
  GraphicsComplex[
   newpts, {
    EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[ColorData[97][1]], 
    Polygon[newtopology[[All, 1 ;; 4]]],
    EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], 
    Polygon[newtopology[[All, 5 ;; 8]]]
    }
   ],
  Table[Text[i, newpts[[i]], Background -> LightBlue], {i, 1, 
    Length[newpts]}]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. This is what i want.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of pain, I found a solution. I hope there are no bugs.

```
GenerateGridMesh[aa_, bb_, nx_, ny_] := 
  Block[{x = 0., y = 0., dx, dy, meshnodes = {}, i, j, 
    meshtopology = {}, allcoords, k, topolsz, l, edge, vec, data, a, 
    b, c},
   vec = {};
   edge = {};
   dx = aa/(2 nx);
   dy = bb/(2 ny);
   For[i = 1, i <= 2 ny + 1, i++,
    If[OddQ[i] == True,
     For[j = 1, j <= 2 nx + 1, j++,
       AppendTo[vec, {x, y}];
       x += dx ;
       ];
     ,
     For[k = 1, k <= nx + 1, k++,
       AppendTo[vec, {x, y}];
       x += 2 dx ;
       ];
     ];
    x = 0;
    y += dy;
    ];
   meshtopology = {};
   a = 0;
   b = 0;
   a = 1;
   l = 0;
   c = 3 nx + 2;
   For[i = 1, i <= ny, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= nx, j++,
     data = {a, a + 2, 3 nx + 4 + a, 3 nx + 3 + b, a + 1, 
       2 nx + 3 + l, 3 nx + 4 + b, 2 nx + 2 + l};
     AppendTo[meshtopology, data];
     a += 2;
     b += 2;
     l += 1;
     ];
    l = 3 nx + 2 + c (i - 1);
    a = 3 nx + 3 + c (i - 1);
    b = 3 nx + 2 + c (i - 1);
    ];
   allcoords = 
    Table[vec[[meshtopology[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[meshtopology]}, {j, 1, Length[meshtopology[[1]]]}];
   {allcoords, vec, meshtopology}
   ];
(*This function generates a mesh graphic*)
GenerateGraphics[nodes_, topology_, order_] := 
  Block[{meshvis, nodevis, v},
   v = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8};
   meshvis = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
      GraphicsComplex[nodes, Polygon[topology[[All, v]]]]}];
   nodevis = 
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], 
      MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1, {-1.5, 1.5}] &, nodes], {Blue, 
       Point[nodes]}}];
   {meshvis, nodevis}];
{allcoords, meshnodes, meshtopology} = GenerateGridMesh[2, 2, 3, 2];
{meshvis, nodevis} = GenerateGraphics[meshnodes, meshtopology, 2];
Show[meshvis, nodevis]
```

`meshtopology`

`{{1, 3, 14, 12, 2, 9, 13, 8}, {3, 5, 16, 14, 4, 10, 15, 9}, {5, 7, 18,
   16, 6, 11, 17, 10}, {12, 14, 25, 23, 13, 20, 24, 19}, {14, 16, 27, 
  25, 15, 21, 26, 20}, {16, 18, 29, 27, 17, 22, 28, 21}}`

[image]